# How to send array value for one the key for rest assured request

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Below is the expected request which should hit the system but while sending it the array becoming string?

Expected
`{ "class": "A", "subUsecases": [ "string1", "String2" ] }`

To generate the above, I am creating the Array object and sending the request but its turning out to be some like this in rest assured request.

Actual

```
{"Class": "A", "subClass": "[\"String1\",\"String2\"]"}
```

Due to above actuall result, api is thinking it a string for subClass and not treating it as array. But code wants it to be an array for subClass.

I am using hasmap to create the above. Like this

```
@Test
    public void mm(){
        HashMap<String,String> queryParam = new HashMap<>();
        queryParam.put("CLASS","A");
        queryParam.put("subClass", arrayMethod("String1","String2"));
    }

    public String arrayMethod(String s1, String s2){
        org.json.simple.JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        array.add(s1);
        array.add(s2);

        return array.toJSONString();
    }
```

queryParam is going as jsonbody.

Now How to send as expected json body instead of actual json body.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to use a class as result

Comment: Do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `Map` to:

```
HashMap<String, Object> queryParam = new HashMap<>();
```

And create a regular list or array instead of using `JSONArray` object. `array.toJSONString()` produces already `JSON` string which you put as value to another object.

```
queryParam.put("subClass", Arrays.asList("String1", "String2"));
```